# io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite sqliteplugin.js with Ripple

Tags: cordova, ripple

I am working on cordova based hybrid mobile application using VS 2013, sqliteplugin.js (io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite), angularjs, jquerymobile,  Ripple for running application during development.

I have added sqliteplugin and here is my index.html file

```
<script src="plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/Lawnchair-adapter/test-www/lib/qunit.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/Lawnchair-adapter/test-www/lib/json2.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/Lawnchair-adapter/test-www/lib/lawnchair.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/www/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/Lawnchair-adapter/test-www/Lawnchair-sqlitePlugin.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/Lawnchair-adapter/test-www/lawnchair-spec.js"></script>

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false); //jshint ignore:line
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false); //jshint ignore:line
    appObj.spa.status.deviceReady = true;
    appObj.spa.status.cordovaReady = appObj.spa.api.cordova.cordovaReady();
    appObj.spa.api.angular.bootstrap();
```

Below is my code where i am creating database and then creating tables in it..

```
    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('vitaegodb', '1.0', 'VITAE_Go_Db', 200000);
    db.transaction(createTables, errorCB, successCB);

}
```

function createTables(tx) {

```
    var createtblActivityCancel = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tblActivityCancel]([ActivityId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,[DayPlanId] [int] NOT NULL,[WorklistId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,[ResourceId] [int] NOT NULL,[ReasonId] [int] NOT NULL,[Remark] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[ChangeState] [int] NOT NULL,[Synchronized] [bit] NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_tblActivityCancel] PRIMARY KEY([ActivityId],[DayPlanId]));";


    tx.executeSql(createtblActivityCancel);

}
```

Now, i am getting a popup "I haz CheezBurger ??" in ripple saying "We seem to be missing some stuff :("

Also in sqliteplugin.js file it is thorwing an exception in below function :

```
 mycb = function(result) {
  var last, q, r, res, type, _i;
  last = result.length - 1;
  for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= last ? _i <= last : _i >= last; i = 0 <= last ? ++_i : --_i) {
    r = result[i];
    type = r.type;`enter code here`
    res = r.result;
    q = mycbmap[i];
    if (q) {
      if (q[type]) {
        q[type](res);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I found result is undefined and hence when its trying to find 
last = result.length - 1;
it is thrwing exception can't find length of undefined.
Ripple error
![Exception of SQLiteplugin.js file][1]

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) provides an interface to a **native** SQLite database. This means that for each supported platform (Android, iOS, Windows, etc.) there's native code which the JS part of the plugin calls.

Ripple is an emulator that supports most of the Cordova/Phonegap APIs but isn't an actual platform, so it isn't able to execute native code.

So when you see the "I haz Cheeseburger" message, Ripple is actually saying "You are calling some native code that I can't understand".

In other words, you can't use this (or any) plugin that calls native code within Ripple.

If you want to test the database within Ripple, your best bet is to add some conditional logic to use a WebSQL database in the Ripple environment, since the interface to this is the same as to the native SQLite DB via the plugin.

Comment: but why result in the function is 'undefined' ?

Comment: result is undefined because this would contain the value passed by the native code to the Javascript callback function. But since there isn't any native code to call it, there's no result. As I said in my answer, this plugin won't work with Ripple.

Comment: Thanks Dave, will check and update the post accordingly.